# Impossible restore backup file in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, backup

I have a backup file from a SPSite (backup.bak) and when i go to restore in another server i get this message:

"Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version ’14.0.0.7123′ or later"

I have installed the identical patch version 14.0.7123.5000 in my server with the MS14-022 Patch (wss2010-kb2837588-fullfile-x64-glb.exe)

After, i have run the configuration wizard and the content database is upgraded with  the exactly version 14.0.7123.5000.

When I tried restore the site get the same error message:

"Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version ’4.0.145.0′ or later"

But what’s that? This is incredible!!!

Seem impossible restore my backup, please any idea!!

Comment: did you checked this link http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.in/2014/05/restore-spsite-your-backup-is-from.html#.U60q-vmSyQw?

Comment: Please, have a look at [this](http://goo.gl/WtPqWF). may help, I hope so.

Comment: Thanks guys! but any solution work for me..

Comment: Sorry, i want to say that don't work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things if you are exporting / importing the site with .bak extension then sometime it cause the issue.

I would recommend, perform a fresh backup using the powershel.

```
Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Once you move the `.bak` files to dev server, then run the restore command.

```
Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Comment: Thanks Wagas, but your solution is very obiously and is the correct way, but dont work for me because my problem is between versions..  

My problem is other, i have a backup file with .bak extension from backup operation in stsadm and this is not a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: that's fine, but what i am trying to say...get the fresh backup from the source server then try to restore it? what method you trying to restore...restore or import?

Comment: I wish!! bu i haven't the old server was broken.. Thanks again!

Comment: ok, which method you try, import or restore? try both

Comment: restore because accept a file with .bak extension. Import operation needs a .cmp file....

Comment: My problem is the version. Sharepoint wants a especific version when i try retore operation and when a update the server and give the same version Sharepoint says that wants another version diferent.. I can't update more...

Comment: for me, your backup is corrupted. did you perform the backup or you just get the .bak file

Comment: I did the backup with: "stsadm -o backup -url htp://xxxx -filename c:\xxx.bak". The file is not corrupted because the operation finished correctly. Thanks a lot!